# ios googlemap deploy. doesn't show

Tags: ios, iphone, google-maps

I use google map.

Xcode works normally.
Even if it is connected directly from the local, it works normally.

However, Apple is not show during testing.

I know there is an API KEY for development and deploy.
What should I check?

[enter image description here](https://i.stack.imgur.com/7XSsN.png)

Comment: Is it safe to assume that you followed this [tutorial](https://developers.google.com/maps/documentation/ios-sdk/start) correctly? 2, show us your code. It is hard to pinpoint your problem

Comment: When debugging in xcode, it works normally.
So that's not a code problem. It seems like a setup problem. Do I still need the code?